# MariaDB event privileges/grants

Tags: mariadb, permissions, role, mysql-event

I'm having multiple databases in MariaDB and I'm trying to set up an automation task, that would take data from one database/scheme and insert them with some transformation to another one.

For this purpose I have a user `esttfy` with the following privileges (among others) and roles:

```sql
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO "utl_logging";
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON "utl"."event_log" TO "utl_logging";
GRANT EXECUTE ON PACKAGE "utl"."pkg_log" TO "utl_logging";
GRANT EXECUTE ON PACKAGE BODY "utl"."pkg_log" TO "utl_logging";

GRANT "utl_logging" TO "esttfy_default"; -- role granted to the default role
GRANT "esttfy_default" TO "esttfy"@"%"; -- default role

GRANT EXECUTE ON PACKAGE "etl"."pkg_load" TO "esttfy"@"%";
GRANT EXECUTE ON PACKAGE BODY "etl"."pkg_load" TO "esttfy"@"%";
```

NOTE: I'm running MariaDB with `SQL_MODE=oracle` allowing me to use packages.

When I log into MariaDB as user `esttfy`, I'm able to run the following script without any issues:

```sql
DELIMITER //
BEGIN
    etl.pkg_load.p_load_main();
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

However, when I create an event as follows

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE DEFINER = esttfy@'%' EVENT etl.ev_load
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
STARTS timestamp(date_format(date_add(now(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00'))
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO
    etl.pkg_load.p_load_main();
```

the event just doesn't run and produces the following error into the log instead:

```
[ERROR] Event Scheduler: [esttfy@%][etl.ev_load] SELECT command denied to user 'esttfy'@'%' for table 'event_log'
[Note] Event Scheduler: [esttfy@%][etl.ev_load] At line 1 in etl.ev_load
[Note] Event Scheduler: [esttfy@%].[etl.ev_load] event execution failed.
```

The only `event_log` table on the server is the one in database `utl`, which is granted for `SELECT` and `INSERT` to role `utl_logging` which is then granted to role `esttfy_default` and user `esttfy`.

The package body `etl.pkg_load` is defined as shown below

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY etl.pkg_load SQL SECURITY INVOKER AS

    c_cschema utl.event_log.cschema%TYPE := 'etl';
    c_cpackage utl.event_log.cpackage%TYPE := 'pkg_load';

    ...
```

It seems the variables definition in the header of the package body is causing the error. I'm having hard times to understand why because the script/loading procedure being executed from CLI runs smoothly, but when executed from the MariaDB `event` it produces a strange error. Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. For some reason, the event was run without the (default) role `esttfy_default`. I changed the event to the following:

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE DEFINER = esttfy@'%' EVENT etl.ev_load
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
STARTS timestamp(date_format(date_add(now(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00'))
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO
BEGIN
    SET ROLE esttfy_default;
    etl.pkg_load.p_load_main();
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

and it works!